# ORDER BY with CASE - multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example table:

```
tableId  otherValue
1        4
2        3
3        2
4        1
```

I am selecting the data in a specific order based on the `tableId` - when value is 1 or 2 then return it, otherwise return others. Now I would like to add an additional sorting parameter based on `otherValue`.

Simply adding it after `CASE` in `ORDER BY` as presented below will not work since `WITH TIES` is used.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES tableId, otherValue
FROM exampleTable
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN tableId IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), otherValue
```

Is there any nicer way to do it than an outer query?

Comment: I don't think so. if you are using SQL 2012 and later, you can use IIF(). it's a little cleaner.

Comment: order by 1 or 2? this means you are already ordering either by tableId or otherValue

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
select * from exampleTable
where tableID in (1,2) or 
    not exists(select * from exampleTable where tableID in (1,2))
order by othervalue
```